# How to handle multiple search conditions and priorities in Full Text Search

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

Is it possible to reduce executed querys in any way ?
because the way i do that for now is OK but later i can end up with 30 querys and this do not look OK to me

my script

```
$string = 'new movie stars';
$words =  preg_split('/(\/|\s+)/', $string);
print_r($words);
```

> Array ( [0] => new [1] => movie [2] => stars )

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('+$words[0] +$words[1] +$words[2]' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
$query_name = $this->db->query($sql);

if ($query_name->num_rows < 20) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('+$words[0] +($words[1] $words[2])' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
$query_name_two = $this->db->query($sql);
}

if (count($query_name->num_rows + $query_name_two->num_rows) < 20) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('$words[0] $words[1] $words[2]' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
$query_name_three = $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Now would be a great time to read about using [prepared statements in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Its better to ask this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen can you give any example ? if you dont mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Even [`real_escape_string`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/2469308) cannot secure it completely. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) instead.

Now, besides the above suggestion, there are two further fixes possible:

**Fix #1** The php code that you are using to tokenize the input string into words for FTS is insufficient. Some time back, I did create a function to handle this requirement in more robust manner. You *may* use the following instead:

```
/**
 * Method to take an input string and tokenize it into an array of words for Full Text Searching (FTS).
 * This method is used when an input string can be made up of multiple words (let's say, separated by space characters),
 * and we need to use different Boolean operators on each of the words. The tokenizing process is similar to extraction
 * of words by FTS parser in MySQL. The operators used for matching in Boolean condition are removed from the input $phrase.
 * These characters as of latest version of MySQL (8+) are: +-><()~*:""&|
 * We can also execute the following query to get updated list: show variables like 'ft_boolean_syntax';
 * Afterwards, the modified string is split into individual words considering either space, comma, and, period (.) characters.
 * Details at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html
 * @param string $phrase Input statement/phrase consisting of words
 * @return array Tokenized words
 * @author Madhur, 2019
 */
function tokenizeStringIntoFTSWords(string $phrase) : array {
    $phrase_mod = trim(preg_replace('/[><()~*:"&|+-]/', '', trim($phrase)));
    return preg_split('/[\s,.]/', $phrase_mod, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

**Fix #2** It seems that you are trying to rank the searches, by giving priority in following order:

All words in the text `>` First word AND Any of the remaining two words `>` Atleast any of the three words.

But, if you read the [Full Text Search Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html), you can do the sorting by relevance using `MATCH()`, as it also returns the Relevance score.

> When `MATCH()` is used in a `WHERE` clause, the rows returned are
>   automatically sorted with the highest relevance first (**Unfortunately, this works only in NATURAL mode, not BOOLEAN mode**). Relevance
>   values are nonnegative floating-point numbers. Zero relevance means no
>   similarity. Relevance is computed based on the number of words in the
>   row (document), the number of unique words in the row, the total
>   number of words in the collection, and the number of rows that contain
>   a particular word.

So basically, **All words in the text** has already higher relevance than **Atleast any of the three words**. Now, if you need to give higher priority to the first word, you simply need to use `>` operator on the first word. So, all you need is just the following single query:

```
SELECT * FROM movie 
WHERE 
  MATCH(name) 
  AGAINST('>:first_word :second_word :third_word ..and so on)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY 
  MATCH(name) 
  AGAINST('>:first_word :second_word :third_word ..and so on)' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
  DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: NATURAL mode isnt what i looking for as i understand your query will do : search with higher priority $words[0]  or $words[1] or $words[2]

Comment: @GameClubStreaming my query isnt using `NATURAL MODE`, but Boolean Mode only. Give the query a try, and I believe the results should be ranked as per your requirements. If not, please provide some sample data proving your case

Comment: can you join this ? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o2zmTuQXtSNa4XyMrxZe5M/1#&togetherjs=FjeBqbKhlt  i setup the query with result that are correct atm , if you try your query will print all results

Comment: @GameClubStreaming check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o2zmTuQXtSNa4XyMrxZe5M/3

Comment: that look fine i will accept it like correct answer, if i understand you right i wont need any more those if statement

Comment: @GameClubStreaming yes you dont need any more IFs; `BOOLEAN` mode provides a lot of operators, and that should be able to satisfy your requirements in a single query itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199624/discussion-between-gameclub-streaming-and-madhur-bhaiya).